# NOT IN does works with array of string

Tags: postgresql

I was writing a PostgreSQL function. In that function, I had 2 cases to be checked.

1. Check if a value exists in the array given
2. Check if a value does not exist in an array

below are the queries I'm trying

For the first case

```
SELECT * FROM  TableA A 
    INNER JOIN TableB B on A.inuri = B.resource_uri 
    INNER JOIN TableI I  on I.resource_id = B.resource_id
    WHERE B.resource_type like '%%' AND 
    outuri='./a/b(d91dae45-9e10-43c5-bf08-f52ec80732d3)' AND (("isDeleted"='true')) OR A.inuri = ANY
    (
        '{./a/b(d91dae45-9e10-43c5-bf08-f52ec80732d3)/c(ee0cc326-fbaf-4d04-a9a6-31d515dea1f6),
        ./a/b(d91dae45-9e10-43c5-bf08-f52ec80732d3)/c(ee0cc326-fbaf-4d04-a9a6-31d515dea1f6)/d(f0576f89-1e0e-4eda-b498-0976f3e19c5c),
        ./a/b(d91dae45-9e10-43c5-bf08-f52ec80732d3)/c(ee0cc326-fbaf-4d04-a9a6-31d515dea1f6)/d(baf1d782-77f8-4372-9601-47a486f0700a)}'
    )
```

and for the second case

```
SELECT * FROM  TableA A 
    INNER JOIN TableB B on A.inuri = B.resource_uri 
    INNER JOIN TableI I  on I.resource_id = B.resource_id
    WHERE B.resource_type like '%%' AND 
    outuri='./a/b(d91dae45-9e10-43c5-bf08-f52ec80732d3)' AND (("isDeleted"='false')) AND A.inuri NOT IN
    (
        '{./a/b(d91dae45-9e10-43c5-bf08-f52ec80732d3)/c(ee0cc326-fbaf-4d04-a9a6-31d515dea1f6),
        ./a/b(d91dae45-9e10-43c5-bf08-f52ec80732d3)/c(ee0cc326-fbaf-4d04-a9a6-31d515dea1f6)/d(f0576f89-1e0e-4eda-b498-0976f3e19c5c),
        ./a/b(d91dae45-9e10-43c5-bf08-f52ec80732d3)/c(ee0cc326-fbaf-4d04-a9a6-31d515dea1f6)/d(baf1d782-77f8-4372-9601-47a486f0700a)}'
    )
```

The first case works without any issue. But for the second case, it won't work when multiple values are passed.

Eg: if I give

```
A.inuri NOT IN
    (
        '{./a/b(d91dae45-9e10-43c5-bf08-f52ec80732d3)/c(ee0cc326-fbaf-4d04-a9a6-31d515dea1f6)/d(f0576f89-1e0e-4eda-b498-0976f3e19c5c)}'
    )
```

I will get all except **./a/b(d91dae45-9e10-43c5-bf08-f52ec80732d3)/c(ee0cc326-fbaf-4d04-a9a6-31d515dea1f6)/d(f0576f89-1e0e-4eda-b498-0976f3e19c5c)**. But if I give 3 of them it is not validating anything. I will get all 3 items listed in the NOT IN Clause

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
A.inuri <> ALL (.... your array here ...)
```